# Optimizing a query involving the greatest lower bound of a set of times PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.2

I am on a forked version of PostgreSQL 8.2 that has been adapted to MPP. I am trying to essentially compute the greatest lower bound for a range of tiestamps from two larger tables. Here is an example of the aformentioned tables:

```
Table A
|source_ip (inet type)  |s_time (date type)    |
------------------------------------------------
|10.50.43.200           | 2013-02-21 01:47:08  |
|10.50.43.200           | 2013-02-21 01:47:38  |
|10.50.43.200           | 2013-02-21 01:47:41  |
|10.50.43.200           | 2013-02-25 17:05:00  |
|10.50.43.200           | 2013-02-25 17:05:03  |
|10.50.43.200           | 2013-02-25 17:05:04  |
|10.50.43.200           | 2013-02-25 17:05:34  |
|10.50.43.200           | 2013-02-25 17:10:01  |
|10.50.43.200           | 2013-02-25 17:12:52  |

Table B
|source_ip (inet type)  |mac (macaddr type)   |l_time (date type)    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|10.50.43.200           | 00:24:d7:99:e9:0c   | 2013-02-20 22:33:47  |
|10.50.43.200           | 00:24:d7:99:e9:0c   | 2013-02-20 23:07:32  |
|10.50.43.200           | 00:24:d7:99:e9:0c   | 2013-02-20 23:13:04  |
|10.50.43.200           | 00:24:d7:99:e9:0c   | 2013-02-21 00:02:56  |
|10.50.43.200           | 00:24:d7:99:68:14   | 2013-02-25 17:04:56  |
|10.50.43.200           | 00:24:d7:99:68:14   | 2013-02-25 17:04:59  |
|10.50.43.200           | 00:24:d7:99:68:14   | 2013-02-25 17:26:15  |
```

For each row in table `A` I want to join an additional column that is "the greatest lower bound" for each timestamp in Table `B`.  That is, I want a column that contains the maximum time among all values in Table B and is also less than or equal to the corresponding time in table `A`. The output I'm expecting would look something like the following:

```
 OUTPUT
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 |10.50.43.200  |2013-02-21 01:47:38  |2013-02-21 00:02:56  |
 |10.50.43.200  |2013-02-21 01:47:41  |2013-02-21 00:02:56  |
 |10.50.43.200  |2013-02-25 17:05:00  |2013-02-25 17:04:59  |
 |10.50.43.200  |2013-02-25 17:05:03  |2013-02-25 17:04:59  |
 |10.50.43.200  |2013-02-25 17:05:04  |2013-02-25 17:04:59  |
 |10.50.43.200  |2013-02-25 17:05:34  |2013-02-25 17:04:59  |
```

The following query is what I came up with but I am not sure if using the `max()` aggregate function is the optimal way of achieving this.

So, my question is - can we rewrite the below query without using `max()` to be faster on large data sets (in the 100+ million range)?

```
SELECT a.source_ip,
a.s_Time, max(b.l_Time) AS max_time
    FROM table_a AS a
    INNER JOIN
    table_b AS b
    ON (a.source_ip = b.source_ip AND a.s_time > b.l_time)
    GROUP BY a.source_ip, b.sourcemac, a.s_time
    ORDER BY a.s_time asc;
```

Here is the explain plan:

```
                                                    QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather Motion 72:1  (slice1; segments: 72)  (cost=1519175930.51..1519305453.91 rows=143915 width=48)
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1519175930.51..1519305453.91 rows=143915 width=48)
         Group By: a.source_ip, a.s_time
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=991681.79..1169135585.55 rows=648222862 width=23)
               Hash Cond: a.source_ip = b.source_ip
               Join Filter: a.s_time > b.l_time
               ->  Append-only Columnar Scan on  a  (cost=0.00..1083707.12 rows=1439149 width=15)
               ->  Hash  (cost=487360.24..487360.24 rows=560358 width=15)
                     ->  Seq Scan on  b  (cost=0.00..487360.24 rows=560358 width=15)
(9 rows)
```

I am aware that I can hash the `source_ip`-s to bigints for faster joins. I was also thinking it might be worth experimenting on indexing columns used in the joins but I am not sure what the best optimization strategy is and would love any input from the excellent group of experts in the StackOverflow community. We also tried the `rank()` window function but it has problems on the implementation we are using and is the worst performing function for this type of query we have tested, so the ideal strategy will hopefully avoid any window functions.

Edit:  Added an index on `source_ip`, `start_yime` for table `A` and rewrote the query using the `LIMIT 1` recommendation in the post:

```
                                                           QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather Motion 72:1  (slice2; segments: 72)  (cost=1624120.24..7442384075819.75 rows=145921 width=48)
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1624120.24..7442384075819.75 rows=145921 width=48)
         Group By: a.src, a.start_time
         ->  Append-only Columnar Scan on a  (cost=0.00..1098806.16 rows=1459206 width=15)
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Limit  (cost=708374.49..708374.51 rows=1 width=15)
                 ->  Limit  (cost=708374.49..708374.49 rows=1 width=15)
                       ->  Sort  (cost=708374.49..708376.35 rows=11 width=15)
                             Sort Key (Limit): b.source_ip, b.start_time
                             ->  Result  (cost=708339.65..708347.10 rows=11 width=15)
                                   Filter: $0 = b.source_ip AND $1 > b.start_time
                                   ->  Materialize for deadlock safety  (cost=708339.65..708347.10 rows=11 width=15)
                                         ->  Broadcast Motion 72:72  (slice1; segments: 72)  (cost=0.00..708338.90 rows=11 width=15)
                                               ->  Seq Scan on b  (cost=0.00..708338.90 rows=11 width=15)
```

Comment: What indices are defined?

Comment: Please add the table structure including indexes and the relevant part of your configuration parameters  to the question. (it appears you have set work_mem to an extremely large value) BTW: pg-8.2 is very old.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.src,
    a.s_Time,
    (SELECT b.l_time AS max_time 
       FROM table_b AS b WHERE a.source_ip = b.source_ip
         AND a.s_time > b.l_time 
         ORDER BY b.source_ip DESC, b.l_time DESC /* index on (source_ip, l_time) */
         LIMIT 1)
FROM table_a AS a
ORDER BY a.start_time;
```

I left out the GROUP BY because I don't see a.src and I am not sure if `a.s_time` and `a.start_time` are distinct columns.

Anyway, the idea is that PG is very smart about indexed `LIMIT 1` queries (at least, recent versions are; no vouching for 8.2). Very recent versions *might* be smart enough to transform `MAX` into the equivalent `LIMIT 1` query if desirable, but I am almost certain that is after 8.2.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation I tried your rewrite and posted the explain plan output it still looks like the cost in the query planner using limit instead of max is worse.  For some reason the query planner does not look like it is using the index should I have created it on both tables or just one?

Comment: For my idea to work, table_b(l_time) must have an index. The idea is that instead of a sort, PG will pluck the max from the index. Later  versions of PG are able to deduce this when a MAX is taken on an indexed field—but not, I believe, all the way back to 8.2.

Answer (score 1):

Standard way of finding the maximum without using `MAX()` or `LIMIT` is to use `NOT EXISTS (a record with a larger value)`, like:

```
SELECT a.src, a.s_Time
        , b.l_Time AS max_time
    FROM table_a AS a
    JOIN table_b AS b ON b.source_ip = a.source_ip 
                     AND b.l_time < a.s_time
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM table_b nx
      WHERE nx.b.source_ip = b.source_ip
        AND nx.l_time < a.s_time
        AND nx.l_time > b.l_time
    );
```